# Odd And Even Counter

Tags: c, counter

I want to change this codes to get 20 Numbers from input and count how many are Odd and how many are Even? please can anyone help?!

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int n;
 int odd=0;
 int even=0;
  printf("\nEnter any number \n");
  scanf("%d",&n);    
 if(n%2!=0)
 {
     printf("%d is an odd number",n);
     odd++;
 }
 else
 {
     printf("%d is an even number",n);
     even++;
 }
printf("\n odd%d / even%d",odd,even);
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the code you've put here? what does (not) it do?

Comment: @MukitChowdhury seond attempt after [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29428260/2173917) one. :-)

Comment: Use a `while loop`. Eg: `int i =20; while(i--){ ... }` or a `for loop`. Eg: `for(i=0;i<20;i++)`

Comment: The program works - for one number input.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh So he has one more attempt.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yeah but sadly, _we do not provide from-scratch coding service here._ :-)

Comment: `printf ("odd: 10 / even 10");`. Rationale: of all *possible* integers, exactly half is odd and the other half is even. Run this enough times with random input and you will see it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that solves your problem:

> Tip: You need a loop to take your input 20 times.

```html
void countForJHikaam(){
    int n,i;
    int odd=0;
    int even=0;

    for(i=0;i<20;i++){

        scanf("%d\n",&n);
        if(n%2==0){
            even++;
        }else{odd++;}

    }
    printf("Odds: %d, Evens: %d",odd,even);
}
```

It won't really help you in learning. Now go learn what a function is.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int n;
   int odd=0;
   int even=0;
   printf("\nEnter any number \n");

   while(scanf("%d",&n))    
     (n%2) ? (++odd) : (++even);

   printf("\n odd%d / even%d",odd,even);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
     int odd=0,even=0,no,count=20;
     printf("Enter the 20 numbers...\n");
here:
     scanf("%d",&no);
     (no%2==0)? odd++ : even++ ;`
     count--;
     if(count>0)
     goto here;

     printf("No of odd numbers... :%d\n",odd);
     printf("No of even numbers... :%d\n",even);
}
```